# UNIX/Oracle - how to spool a LONG string whose length is greater than 32767 chars

Tags: bash, oracle, unix, oracle11g

Below script write data from Oracle table to file.

Problem: When the length of a string exceeds 32767 characters (let say 45000) then I get the string till 32767 characters in the file only.

How to spool such a long string to the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
.
.
sqlplus -s $USER/$PWD@$SID <<ENDSQL > $SQLOUT

set trimout on 
set trimspool on 
set HEAD OFF
set TAB OFF
set FEED OFF
set echo off
SET TERMOUT OFF 
set linesize 32767 long 32767 longchunksize 32767 pagesize 0 

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;

spool $EXTFILE

select SQL_FULLTEXT||chr(10)||';' from v$sql; 

spool off
.
.
#Unix script ends
```

UTL may help here but cant use it.

Comment: This isn't really a `perl` question is it? I mean "Perl may help" I suppose it technically correct, but it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: SQL*Plus's line size seems to be the issue, not the shell (which might not be `bash` if you use `/bin/sh`)

Comment: look at your script again, you SET LONG and LONGCHUNKSiZE to 32767 - that's not a coincidence

Comment: From the doc, the maximum value for SET LONG is 2,000,000,000 bytes, not 32767. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121

Comment: set long 20000
I am SYSTEM on localhost:1521/orcl12c > select SQL_FULLTEXT||chr(10)||';' from v$sql
  2  where length(sql_fulltext) > 15000
  3* fetch first 1 rows only;

I get back 17,062 characters on my first go of it

Comment: SET LONG 100000 - Now the whole query is written to the file. But it splits the string after 32767 chars and continue from the next line. This make the string incorrect. Any way to write the string in one line?